# Javascript / CSS - Rotation after CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, rotation

I'm messing around with CSS animations at the moment and there is this behaviour I came across that I don't understand.

I have a div container to which I set an infinite CSS animation. The animation will just rotate the div back and forth. At any given point I want to manually adjust the rotation of the div to a specific and absolute angle (-90 degress in my case).

The problem I'm experiencing is, that whenever I (or animejs) is trying to set the rotation to the fixed -90 degrees after the CSS animation has started, the following rotation somehow depends on the CSS animation changes. I also tried to pause the CSS animation before without success.

I just want to trigger an animejs animation that always goes smoothly to -90 degrees from its current state (given by the CSS animation).

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('testdiv');

document.addEventListener('keypress', function onPress(event) {
    div.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';

    if (event.key == 'q') {
      div.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'; 
    }

    if(event.key == 'e') {
      div.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'; 
    }

    if(event.key == 's') {
      div.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    }
});
```

```css
@keyframes animation {
    to {
        transform: rotate(15deg); 
    }
}

#testdiv {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;   
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;

    animation-name: animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;  
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ls1ytf4h/

`<div id="testdiv"></div>`

If you run this and press Q or E in its inital state, it will change its rotation to either -90 or 180 degrees. If you press S, it will start the inifite CSS animation. After the animation started, press Q or E again (switch multiple times from Q to E to see the difference).
As you can see it doesn't go back to the absolute -90 degrees. It seem to work relative to something, but I cannot figure out to what. animejs is working in the same weird way, when I try to smoothly go to the -90 degrees from its current state.

Is there some way to avoid this behaviour?

Btw. was my first question here, so I hope I didn't do something wrong ;)

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out :

```js
var div = document.getElementById('testdiv');

document.addEventListener('keypress', function onPress(event) {
    div.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
    div.style.animationName = 'none';

    if (event.key == 'q') {
      div.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'; 
    }

    if(event.key == 'e') {
      div.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'; 
    }

    if(event.key == 's') {
      div.style.animationName = 'animation';
      div.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    }
});
```

```css
@keyframes animation {
    to {
        transform: rotate(15deg); 
    }
}

#testdiv {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;   
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;

    animation-name: animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;  
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```